# Galois action on local deformation ring

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, galois-representations, galois-cohomology

Let ${\Bbb Q}_p$ be a local field. For a prime $q \not= p$, we consider an irreducible residual Galois representation

$\overline{\rho} \colon {\mathrm{Gal}}(\overline{{\Bbb Q}}_p/{{\Bbb Q}_p}) \to \mathrm{GL}_2({\Bbb F}_q)$.

If we make base change from ${\Bbb Q}_p$ to 
${\Bbb Q}^{\mathrm{ur}}_p$, we obtain the Galois representation

$\overline{\rho} \colon {\mathrm{Gal}}(\overline{\Bbb Q}_p/{{\Bbb Q}^{\mathrm{ur}}_p}) \to \mathrm{GL}_2({\Bbb F}_q)$,

to which we can associate Mazur's deformation ring $R$ over ${\Bbb Z}_q$, which satisfies the universality with respect to the lift $\rho$ of $\overline{\rho}$. That is, $\rho$ is a Galois representation

$\rho \colon {\mathrm{Gal}}(\overline{{\Bbb Q}}_p/{{\Bbb Q}^{\mathrm{ur}}_p}) \to \mathrm{GL}_2(A)$,

where $A$ is a local complete noetherian ring such that $A/{\frak m}_A = {\Bbb F}_q$.

The Diamond parameter $S$, which takes care of tame ramifications of ${\Bbb Q}_p$, will live in $R$. I do not know the explicit representation of $R$, but want to know the Galois action on it.

More precisely, let us choose the topological generator $\sigma$ of $\widehat{\Bbb Z} \cong {\mathrm{Gal}}({\Bbb Q}^{\mathrm{ur}}_p/{\Bbb Q}_p)$. We extend this to 
$\widetilde{\sigma} \in \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\Bbb Q}_p/{\Bbb Q}_p)$. 
For the universal Galois representation

$\rho \colon {\mathrm{Gal}}(\overline{{\Bbb Q}}_p/{{\Bbb Q}^{\mathrm{ur}}_p}) \to \mathrm{GL}_2(R)$,

we consider the Galois representation

$\widetilde{\rho} \colon {\mathrm{Gal}}(\overline{{\Bbb Q}}_p/{{\Bbb Q}^{\mathrm{ur}}_p}) \to \mathrm{GL}_2(R)$ ; $\widetilde{\rho}(g) \colon= \rho(\widetilde{\sigma}g{\widetilde{\sigma}}^{-1})$.

Then up to the inner automorphism by element $h \in \mathrm{GL}_2(R)$ such that $\overline{\rho}(\widetilde{\sigma})=\overline{h} \in {\mathrm{GL}}_2({\Bbb F}_q)$, $\widetilde{\rho}$ is again a lift of $\overline{\rho}$ in Mazur's sense (in short, we consider the map $g \mapsto h^{-1}\widetilde{\rho}h \in {\Bbb GL}_2(R)$).

By universality, there is a morphism

$\sigma^{\sharp} \colon R \to R$

such that $\sigma^{\sharp} \circ \rho = \widetilde{\rho}$

I would like to ask

### Q. For the Diamond parameter $S \in R$, does the following equality hold?

### $\sigma^{\sharp}(S) = S^p$.

Comment: Dear Pierre, I think you need to assume _absolute_ irreducibility and that your $A$ and $R$ are the same ring. But can you make the action by __functoriality__ explicit? I do not understand how you get it.

Comment: Sorry, Filippo. I am too stupid to answer your question. Anyhow, up to conjugacy we can get the natural action of σ on R. For instance, by conjugation of the extension of σ to Gal(Q_p^bar/Q_p).